# Floating elements to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is very specific, and will haunt any web developer from the moment he/she will read it. So be carefull!

I've got a layout planned for a website I'm building. The idea is that there is are tilted `<hr/>` elements on the page, which the text will wrap around to (see image below. The black line represents the `<hr/>`)

[image: the way it should be]

What you see are some orange stripes. Each and every one of these are a floating element with widths of `10px`, then `20px`, then `30px` etc.
The black line represents where they stop, and thus where they cut off the text.

The big orange area is, as you may guess, a floating element with a width of 0 and a height of `100%` of it's parent minus the height of the 70 other floating elements (the stripes), which is `70px`.

The issue: this doesn't seem to be possible.
What I get is this:

[image: what actually happens]

Since these little stripes are each `1px` high, they will show up, no matter what. But the big one relies on the height of its parents. If I was to fix the parent's height, it would work. But I want the box to be dynamic. This means I should be able to change the text inside. Also, if I were to fix it's height, scaling the page up and down looks disastrous.

What I need to happen is this: The first, big floating element should be taking up the space it needs `(100% - 70px)`, without giving it's parent a fixed height, while keeping it floated.

I am going to reward the person solving this with all the reputation I can put in, since this has been pestering me for months.

For people trying to solve the issue. There are some thoughts that may help:

1. Table cells can align elements to it's bottom
2. I've tried rotating in a lot of ways. Too bad there's no upside down text.
3. I've tried adding margins, paddings and borders to the first floating div. Not one combination has worked so far.
4. I don't actually want the elements to float. This is just the way I chose to try, because I don't know another way to wrap text around an element. You are free to try ANYTHING you want, as long as the text inside can be changed, and it looks as good when scaled up or down, as it does normally.
5. I think the only solution is to use Javascript to calculate what height the div would need.

Here is all the code packed into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5o1uja0/)

EDIT: I think I do know the solution. I just don't know how to program it.

With Javascript, the browser should calculate the height of the content (text, images, their margins, etc.) inside the container. Then, `#lw` should change to that height.
After that has happened, `#lw` should be shrunk down by 1px. After that has happened, a check should be made to see whether the content changed in height.
If this has happened, the browser should check if the height of the content's height is bigger than the height of `#lw` + 70px.
If it did not get higher than that, the process should repeat. If it did, `#lw` should be scaled down by 1px again, and the process should stop.
When resizing the window, the process should start from the beginning.

This seems like one hell of a job, and I would gratefully take on the challange if I were to know JS.
I guess I'm off to Codecadamy.

EDIT:

In the meantime, I have come up with a less complex version of this problem.
I have looked into css-shapes, and found out that these will allow me to do what the 70 floating elements did, with one element.
I have made another set of files, BUT There is a js file needed for it to work. What I'll do here is paste the HTML and CSS as code, and link to the js code.

Just like the older version, the code should measure what the optimal height is. In my code, I have added a `<script>` tag with an exact description of what should happen.

I think I start to look lazy, since I can't give any input regarding actual Javascript code.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
            <script src='js/shapes.polyfill.min.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="polybreak"></div>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus enim arcu, porttitor vitae hendrerit euismod, efficitur pretium nulla. Sed a justo nulla. Aenean vel erat purus. In velit arcu, lacinia in justo in, vestibulum pellentesque mauris. Phasellus quis eros nunc. Vivamus fringilla euismod est, eget consectetur lacus cursus et. Fusce at arcu ac turpis laoreet feugiat nec a nulla.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque vehicula mollis leo non tempus. Praesent scelerisque dui felis. Suspendisse tristique, sapien egestas semper cursus, elit quam facilisis sapien, sit amet ornare odio nibh sed nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum libero nisi, efficitur id felis non, maximus ultricies sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce rhoncus nibh enim, eget dignissim neque placerat et. Nam sit amet placerat sapien. Quisque vitae risus ac dolor porttitor tincidunt.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Nullam volutpat, lorem vitae ultricies lobortis, ligula ligula posuere erat, sed gravida sapien nisi non ante. Aliquam tellus sapien, placerat mollis tempor quis, consequat imperdiet magna. Etiam cursus ornare mauris sit amet varius. Sed dignissim euismod felis, at aliquet est fringilla at. Duis lorem nunc, imperdiet nec rhoncus et, egestas quis nunc. Nulla imperdiet elementum libero consequat tempor. Donec ante nunc, pellentesque nec ex dapibus, auctor sagittis ipsum. Phasellus ut est ex.
                </p>
            </div>
            <script src='js/shapes.polyfill.min.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                On load and on resize:
                Make #polybreak the same height as #container + 60px.

                Subtract 1px off #polybreak''s height and check: is #container higher than #polybreak? If so, add 1px and stop. If not, repeat.
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
}

#container{
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#polybreak{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: polygon(0 calc(100% - 100px), 700px calc(100% - 1px), 700px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 99px));
}
```

Link to the raw js code
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill/master/shapes-polyfill.min.js

Comment: `calc(100% - 70px)` can’t work, because the parent element doesn’t have a `height` set to base the 100% on to begin with. Using JS is your only option right now I think – until [CSS Shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/) get implemented.

Comment: @CBroe: Exactly my thoughts, only option might be using SVG's somehow, but I am less well versed in those, so going through some specs now~ Edit: Looks like that would require javascript as well though of course due to the dynamic height requirement.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the link to CSS Shapes. Those things are EXACLY what I need

Comment: Thanks @DavidMulder for looking into it. Every bit of info could help

Answer (score 2):

As everybody is posting Javascript answers either way, let's throw in an actual solution into the bunch. The problem even using Javascript is that there is no defined way to 'calculate' the final height of `#lw` as predicting the behaviour of the text wrapping is impossible.

```
//Get a nice starting point
Zepto(".lW").hide();
var sh = document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollHeight;
document.getElementById("lw").style["height"] = sh - 60 + "px";
Zepto(".lW").show();

//Start the search
var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("lw").style["height"]);
var difference = Infinity;
var bestheight = 0;
var i = 0;
var checker = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    height += 1;
    document.getElementById("lw").style["height"] = height + "px";
    var sh = document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollHeight;

    //Now the interesting part, we don't want to get the first situation
    // where the #lw is greater than the floats, what we want is the most
    // optimal part, which we are going to search over a certain pixel range.
    // In this case that pixel range is hardcoded as 30 pixels.
    if(Math.abs(height + 70 - parseInt(sh)) < difference){
        difference = Math.abs(height + 70 - parseInt(sh));
        bestheight = height;
    }
    if(i>30){
        clearInterval(checker);
        document.getElementById("lw").style["height"] = bestheight + "px";
    }
},0);
```

Here is JSFiddle of the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/d5o1uja0/5/).

[image]

Comment: And regarding the last word which is pushed out of the box to the right by the float... you will have to ask a different question I fear why it's not going under the floats as I would've expected.

Comment: Hey, David. Thanks for the help. This did seem to work at first.
Although, as I was playing around with the amount of text inside, I noticed that not only the last word would occasionally jump out, but sometimes even whole lines of text!
What I have done in the meantime is try and think of a somewhat simpler alternative that requires less JavaScript. I will update my question again. In 8 hours I can add my bounty (which will be at least 160) Thanks for the answer! Bedankt

Comment: @GustvandeWal: The lines/words getting pushed out is a consequence of the floating boxes itself, see for example this non JS case: http://jsfiddle.net/d5o1uja0/9/ (and try increasing 443 to 444 to confirm that 443 is actually the absolute best number)

Comment: I don't see how 443 or 444 is better than the other. Anyways. I have kind of simplified the problem. Since you were the only one to come up with a working answer, I'd like to ask you, David, to try and solve the newer version of the problem. I think it won't take that long for you. Thanks

Comment: @GustvandeWal: Regarding the 443px vs the 444px: Because by 444px the wrapper becomes smaller, thus the bottom 'triangle' isn't aligned with the bottom at all anymore (and sticks out about 18px)

Comment: The link you included doesn't bring me to the right jsfiddle, then, I think. I don't see such a thing happening when changing that.

Comment: I have actually checked by hand. The algorithm does exacly the trick. Can you tell me how it does not? Keep in mind that there is new html and css involved.

Comment: @GustvandeWal: My bad, misread your algorithm, apologies. It would indeed work. And check the image I attached temporarily to the bottom of the answer for the 443 vs 444 issue. Edit: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d5o1uja0/13/)@your algorithm, not going to mess around with the css shape polyfill. After all, SO is not a code generation service ;-)

Comment: I guess I'll be on Codecademy, learning Javascript then. Whenever I've programmed the answer, I'll update the question and answer it (might take some time, though). Thanks for your time, David!

Answer (score 1):

Modern CSS has a special module for such tasks: [CSS Shapes](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/). There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill) for it created by Adobe. Maybe it helps?

Comment: I was not going to use CSS Shapes because it isn't supported in most of the browsers.
I will look into this polyfill (I have no idea what it is or means, yet)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give the top div a fixed height (temporary), which is the height you want the non-angled text to appear. It looks like you already have a fixed height for the bottom at 70px.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #topPart { height: 600px }
</style>
```

In order to accommodate different screen heights we will have to calculate the correct dimension for top div and subtract whatever you need on the bottom.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
function resize()
{
    var heights = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById("topPart").style.height = heights - 70 + "px";
}
resize();
window.onresize = function() {
    resize();
};
}
</script>
```

We will run the resize anytime the browser window changes. By doing so the top div and bottom will be in sync.

In the page html add (basic)

```
<div id="topPart">
<p>Some text or other divs whatever you like in here</p>
</div>
<div>
The bottom part - add your staggered divs here
</div>
```

You cannot use 100% and expect it to work, just keep in mind that you need to subtract the bottom portion. I would start off by subtracting about 150 - 200 px to start so you don't run into the bottom of the screen and get messed up.
The page will act dynamically and you can scale the page up and down.

That' my stab at trying to understand this...

Comment: Although this would update neatly, there is a problem with this.
I don't want to have to split up the text manually.
This would also result in a broken layout when scaling the page, because the part with the staggering divs still has nothing dynamic to it.

I really think the topPart, as you called it, should be resizing itself. I do have an idea, though, on how to solve this. I'm going to update my question